# How do I configure PETSc to run long double precision or some other precision that is greater than default?

Tags: petsc

I'm installing PETSc for complex numbers with the C99 standard. I'd like to have it installed using a higher precision than the default (double, I presume) since that will most likely make the LU preconditioner run better. I've tried several different commands that I could google, but it doesn't work. I've searched the manual but haven't found anything on the subject.

I tried invoking `./configure` with the

> precision=longdobule

and

> precision=__float128

with

> download-f-blas-lapack

and

> download-f2cblaslapack

in all four different combinations. The one time I used `download-f2cblaslapack` and `precision=__float128` it did configure successfully but at the next stage when I compiled the libraries I got the following error for every library being compiled:

> error: unknown type name ‘PetscScalar’

What do I have to write to have it configured at a higher precision?

Comment: this sounds like a bug in PETSc itself.  Can you send the complete configure and make/test logs to petsc-maint@mcs.anl.gov for the case where you specified: `--with-precision=__float128 --download-f2cblaslapack` (as suggested by the PETSc documentation [here](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/petsc/documentation/changes/32.html)).